# Redirect to certain page based on URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

Currently I have set up my websites using Apache the following way:

```
...  
ServerName example-one.com  
ServerAlias example-two.com  
ServerAlias example-three.com  
...
```

This way they all point to the same directory and open the same index.php file.
What I want to achieve is to have different landing page for the following but to share the rest of the content.

My question is now if it's possible to append either some GET parameter like index.php?URL=1 etc.
Or is there a better way of achieving this? Maybe using mod_rewrite?

What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is simply load the same template and depending on the URL that is loaded you modify whatever you wish to modify. It'd be something like this in pseudo-PHP-code:

```php
$site = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

switch ($site) {
    case 'example-one.com' : {
        loadTemplate('page.html', ['site' => 1]);
    }
    case 'example-two.com' : {
        loadTemplate('page.html', ['site' => 2]);
    }
    case 'example-three.com' : {
        loadTemplate('page.html', ['site' => 3]);
    }
}
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        [...]
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
        <?php
            switch (site) {
                case 1: {
                    echo "hello";
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    echo "goodbye";
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    echo "later";
                    break;
                }
            }
        ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed; this would be an easy solution for small changes but I have total different index pages.

Comment: Then you could just split the page up in multiple reusable sections (files).